# docker container error when I run command **sed**

Tags: python, docker, shell, sed, docker-compose

when I run  command **sed**, It comes out msg below:

```
sed -i 's/127.0.0.11/8.8.8.8/g' resolv.conf
sed: cannot rename ./sedHaHgXE: Device or resource busy
```

Comment: I already gave an answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72896553/sed-cannot-rename-etc-hosts-device-or-resource-busy

Answer (score 1):

using command below will achive specific string replacement:

```
 echo "$(sed 's/127.0.0.11/8.8.8.8/g' /etc/resolv.conf)" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

[related article](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_343a42207/article/details/92926573)

Comment: This has a high likelihood of replacing the original `resolve.conf` file with an empty file before `sed` begins.