# sed: cannot rename /etc/hosts: Device or resource busy

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run the following command while setting up a dev environment in docker container & getting the above error.

```
./install && source $([ $SHELL = "/bin/zsh" ] && echo ~/.zshrc || echo ~/.bashrc);
```

**Environment:**

- Docker Desktop:4.9.1 (81317)
- Ubuntu: 20.04.4 LTS
- OS: Windows 11 Home

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `sudo`

`sudo ./install && source $([ $SHELL = "/bin/zsh" ] && echo ~/.zshrc || echo ~/.bashrc);`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Same result after adding sudo :( 
Any other tips?

Comment: 1) Are you inside the container?   
2) Can you try other base images?

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate hosts file since it is being managed by docker daemon. To prevent access problems/errors when you manipulate linux system files in docker, you can add "copy" parameter for sed command in your **install** script such as:

```
sed -i -c ...
```

But when you run the container, you will see the unchanged original file. You can think about applying these kind of tricks in **Entrypoint** or **CMD** command sections of Dockerfile, details are at the end.

There are other solutions but valid only during docker build:

1. --add-host

Docker binary has an option "--add-host":
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host

2. extraHosts

If you are working with AWS you have directly corresponded feature "extraHosts":
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html

If you need the modification persistent in container run time you only have the option to modify Entrypoint or CMD:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40430182/1980180